# Form with 'Next' and 'Previous' button in Rails (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, ruby-on-rails

I'm implementing a form in Rails with a 'Next' and 'Previous button' following this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_form_steps

If I copy and paste the code, it will work. However, I want to put each code in its place (following Rails convention). The problem is that when I put my code in my_javascript.js, the code stops working. How can I set up my js file in Rails?

I tried adding the javascript code in my_javascript.js. And I know that Application.js is calling my_javascript.js because I have another function there working properly.

**my_javascript.js:**

```
$(document).on('ready load', function () {
    var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab

    function showTab(n) {
        // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        x[n].style.display = "block";
        //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
        if (n == 0) {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
        }
        if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
        }
        //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
        fixStepIndicator(n)
    }

    function nextPrev(n) {
        // This function will figure out which tab to display
        var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
        if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
        // Hide the current tab:
        x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
        // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
        currentTab = currentTab + n;
        // if you have reached the end of the form...
        if (currentTab >= x.length) {
            // ... the form gets submitted:
            document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
            return false;
        }
        // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
        showTab(currentTab);
    }

    function validateForm() {
        // This function deals with validation of the form fields
        var x, y, i, valid = true;
        x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
        y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
        // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
        for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
            // If a field is empty...
            if (y[i].value == "") {
                // add an "invalid" class to the field:
                y[i].className += " invalid";
                // and set the current valid status to false
                valid = false;
            }
        }
        // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
        if (valid) {
            document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
        }
        return valid; // return the valid status
    }

    function fixStepIndicator(n) {
        // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
        var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
        for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
            x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
        }
        //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
        x[n].className += " active";
    }
});
```

**home.html.erb:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway" rel="stylesheet">
<body>

<form id="regForm" action="/action_page.php">
  <h1>Register:</h1>
  <!-- One "tab" for each step in the form: -->
  <div class="tab">Name:
    <p><input placeholder="First name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="fname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Last name..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="lname"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Contact Info:
    <p><input placeholder="E-mail..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="email"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Phone..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="phone"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Birthday:
    <p><input placeholder="dd" oninput="this.className = ''" name="dd"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="mm" oninput="this.className = ''" name="nn"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="yyyy" oninput="this.className = ''" name="yyyy"></p>
  </div>
  <div class="tab">Login Info:
    <p><input placeholder="Username..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="uname"></p>
    <p><input placeholder="Password..." oninput="this.className = ''" name="pword" type="password"></p>
  </div>
  <div style="overflow:auto;">
    <div style="float:right;">
      <button type="button" id="prevBtn" onclick="nextPrev(-1)">Previous</button>
      <button type="button" id="nextBtn" onclick="nextPrev(1)">Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Circles which indicates the steps of the form: -->
  <div style="text-align:center;margin-top:40px;">
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
    <span class="step"></span>
  </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

**home.scss:**

```css
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }

  body {
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
  }

  #regForm {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 100px auto;
    font-family: Raleway;
    padding: 40px;
    width: 70%;
    min-width: 300px;
  }

  h1 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  input {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  }

  /* Mark input boxes that gets an error on validation: */
  input.invalid {
    background-color: #ffdddd;
  }

  /* Hide all steps by default: */
  .tab {
    display: none;
  }

  button {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    color: #ffffff;
    border: none;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-size: 17px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  button:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }

  #prevBtn {
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
  }

  /* Make circles that indicate the steps of the form: */
  .step {
    height: 15px;
    width: 15px;
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #bbbbbb;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    opacity: 0.5;
  }

  .step.active {
    opacity: 1;
  }

  /* Mark the steps that are finished and valid: */
  .step.finish {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
  }
```

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console? What if you insert `alert('WORKING')` as a second line in my_javascript.js?

Comment: Hello, @Vasilisa. I get the alert and no errors loading the page. However, when I click 'Next' button, I get this error:
(index):528 Uncaught ReferenceError: nextPrev is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):528)

Comment: Actually, I just got it working. I had to take my functions out of ```$(document).on('ready page:load', function () { });```. Thanks for your reply!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those that faced the same problem as me, I had to take the functions out of `$(document).on('ready page:load', function () { });`
My js code became this:

```
$(document).on('ready page:load', function () {
    showTab(currentTab); // Display the current tab
});

var currentTab = 0; // Current tab is set to be the first tab (0)

function nextPrev(n) {
    // This function will figure out which tab to display
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    // Exit the function if any field in the current tab is invalid:
    if (n == 1 && !validateForm()) return false;
    // Hide the current tab:
    x[currentTab].style.display = "none";
    // Increase or decrease the current tab by 1:
    currentTab = currentTab + n;
    // if you have reached the end of the form...
    if (currentTab >= x.length) {
        // ... the form gets submitted:
        document.getElementById("regForm").submit();
        return false;
    }
    // Otherwise, display the correct tab:
    showTab(currentTab);
}

function validateForm() {
    // This function deals with validation of the form fields
    var x, y, i, valid = true;
    x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    y = x[currentTab].getElementsByTagName("input");
    // A loop that checks every input field in the current tab:
    for (i = 0; i < y.length; i++) {
        // If a field is empty...
        if (y[i].value == "") {
            // add an "invalid" class to the field:
            y[i].className += " invalid";
            // and set the current valid status to false
            valid = false;
        }
    }
    // If the valid status is true, mark the step as finished and valid:
    if (valid) {
        document.getElementsByClassName("step")[currentTab].className += " finish";
    }
    return valid; // return the valid status
}

function showTab(n) {
    // This function will display the specified tab of the form...
    var x = document.getElementsByClassName("tab");
    x[n].style.display = "block";
    //... and fix the Previous/Next buttons:
    if (n == 0) {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "none";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("prevBtn").style.display = "inline";
    }
    if (n == (x.length - 1)) {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Submit";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("nextBtn").innerHTML = "Next";
    }
    //... and run a function that will display the correct step indicator:
    fixStepIndicator(n)
}

function fixStepIndicator(n) {
    // This function removes the "active" class of all steps...
    var i, x = document.getElementsByClassName("step");
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].className = x[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }
    //... and adds the "active" class on the current step:
    x[n].className += " active";
}
```